# Trigger Marketo Lightbox on buttonclick

Tags: marketo

The code that Marketo provided us with currently launches a lightbox on page load, but we would like the lightbox to be triggered when a button is clicked.

We would very much appreciate being pointed in the correction direction on how to go about achieving this. I have looked though the Marketo Developer documentation, and through stackoverflow questions tagged 'Marketo' but have been unsuccessful finding an example of how to do this.

Here is the code Marketo has provided us with. I have removed unique identifying numbers like Munkin and formId.

```
<script src="//app-ab02.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_number"></form>
<script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-ab02.marketo.com", "number", number, function (form){MktoForms2.lightbox(form).show();});</script>
```

Comment: You can load your form with style display:none, and then use MktoForms.lightbox() to render it as a lightbox, and remove the display:none on a particular event which you want.

Comment: This worked. I used some jQuery to do essentially what you recommended. However there is a problem I did not anticipate: Upon closing the Marketo modal by clicking the little "x" on the upper right hand corner, the modal cannot be opened again unless the page is reloaded. Is it possible to store the Marketo script in a function and have the button call the function on click?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Put your form anywhere on the page

`<script src="//app-ab02.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_number"></form>`

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#popup-link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjh.marketo.com", "mktoForm_ID", "mktoForm_number", function (form){MktoForms2.lightbox(form).show();
       // Hide the form and display a thank you message
       form.onSuccess(function(form){
                formElem = this.formElem[0];
                formParent = formElem.parentNode;
                formParent.removeChild(formElem);
                formParent.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you!</h3>';
       });
    });
});
</script>
```